# Is there any correct way to segment a large PySpark Dataset in chunks until all rows are exhausted?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a large PySpark dataset called Mkt_all and I have to segment it into several chunks. Now this dataset contains a unique identifier (Primary Key) called 'RETAIL_SITE_ID'. Against each 'RETAIL_SITE_ID', you may contain multiple rows ( all distinct ). Owing to the large size of Mkt_all (almost 50 GB) , I cannot convert this directly to Pandas using toPandas() in Databricks (PySpark).

1. I am partitioning the PySpark data into several chunks, each
   containing multiple records pertaining 125 distinct (RETAIL_SITE_IDs)
2. converting each chunk to Pandas
3. Processing that Pandas dataframe
   (chunk)
4. writing it to DataLakes ( a folder/repository) as csv file
5. reading each file back and concatenating the result
6. dropping all duplicates
7. writing it (concatenated dataframe) back to a folder (Datalakes) as a single csv file

The problem is I am not getting all the RETAIL_SITE_IDs ( or more specifically, not all records are getting captured, some RETAIL_SITE_IDs are missed out)

Here is the code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as sum_col
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, abs as abs_col
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("concatDataFrames") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:<version>") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:<version>") \
    .config("spark.memory.fraction", "0.6") \
    .config("spark.memory.storageFraction", "0.5") \
    .config("spark.rdd.compress", "true") \
    .config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled", "true") \
    .config("spark.memory.offHeap.size", "<offHeapSizeInMB>") \
    .config("spark.storage.level", "DISK_ONLY") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "16g") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Enable Arrow-based columnar data 
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set(
    "spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled", "true"
)
#spark.conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "8g")

# Requried packages

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dbutils.widgets.text("Market Code", "")
dbutils.widgets.text("Time Period", "")
dbutils.widgets.text("Time Block", "5")
Market_Code = dbutils.widgets.get("Market Code")
Time_Period = dbutils.widgets.get("Time Period")
Time_Block = int(dbutils.widgets.get("Time Block"))
Market_Code, Time_Period, Time_Block

##### Mkt_all is being created here ##############
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, monotonically_increasing_id, row_number, floor
from pyspark.sql.window import Window



# Ensure RETAIL_SITE_ID is present and distinct
unique_ids = Mkt_all.select("RETAIL_SITE_ID").distinct()

# Assign a monotonically increasing ID
unique_ids = unique_ids.withColumn("id_index", monotonically_increasing_id())

# Define window specification
windowSpec = Window.orderBy("id_index")

# Assign segment numbers
unique_ids = unique_ids.withColumn("segment", floor((row_number().over(windowSpec) - 1) / 125))

# Join the segments back to the original DataFrame
Mkt_all_segmented = Mkt_all.join(unique_ids, "RETAIL_SITE_ID", "inner")

# Calculate the number of segments
num_segments = Mkt_all_segmented.select("segment").distinct().count()


Final_table = pd.DataFrame()  # Define Final_table outside the loop
# Assuming necessary imports and Spark session creation are done

# Step 2: Process each segment
for segment in range(num_segments):
    segment_df = Mkt_all_segmented.filter(col("segment") == segment)
    # Convert the Spark DataFrame segment to a Pandas DataFrame for processing
    segment_pd_df = segment_df.toPandas()
    **##### Rest of the code which is absolutely correct #######**
    **##### Somewhere above segment_final_table is created ######**
    Final_table = pd.concat([Final_table, segment_final_table], ignore_index=True)
    # Save each segment to a CSV file
    output_path = f"/dbfs/mnt/RAAP_ADLS2/CRM_Network/Forecourt Reconfiguration/Output 2023/New_Trial/{Market_Code}_Pump_Estimation_{segment+1}{Time_Period}.csv"
    Final_table.to_csv(output_path, sep=',', index=False)

#####  End of for loop ################

# Step 3: Read and concatenate results
final_dfs = []
for segment in range(num_segments):
    print(segment)
    segment_path = f"/dbfs/mnt/RAAP_ADLS2/CRM_Network/Forecourt Reconfiguration/Output 2023/New_Trial/{Market_Code}_Pump_Estimation_{segment+1}{Time_Period}.csv"
    segment_df = pd.read_csv(segment_path)
    final_dfs.append(segment_df)

concatenated_Final_Table = pd.concat(final_dfs, ignore_index=True)
# # Remove duplicate rows across all columns, keeping only the first occurrence
concatenated_Final_Table = concatenated_Final_Table.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
# Write the concatenated final table back
concatenated_Final_Table.to_csv(f"/dbfs/mnt/RAAP_ADLS2/CRM_Network/Forecourt Reconfiguration/Output 2023/New_Trial/COUNTRY/{Market_Code}_Pump_Estimation{Time_Period}.csv", sep=',', index=False)
```

Comment: Why can't you do all the operations in Pyspark rather than converting into Pandas and so on.

Comment: I did but the output it gives me has got lesser number of records (that is some RETAIL_SITE_IDs are completely ignored) , I have tried this many times.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible example? Otherwise no can help you